# Grails 4 JWT token issue

Tags: rest, grails, jwt

I am using grails spring-security-rest to generate the JWT token.

my config looks like below

> grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName =
> 'com.kps.User'
> grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName =
> 'com.kps.UserRole' grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className =
> 'com.kps.Role' grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType =
> "InterceptUrlMap"
> grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
> [pattern: '/',               access: ['permitAll']],    [pattern:
> '/error',          access: ['permitAll']],    [pattern: '/index',
> access: ['permitAll']],   [pattern: '/index.gsp',      access:
> ['permitAll']],   [pattern: '/shutdown',       access: ['permitAll']],
> [pattern: '/assets/**',      access: ['permitAll']],    [pattern:
> '/**/js/**',       access: ['permitAll']],    [pattern: '/**/css/**',
>
> access: ['permitAll']],   [pattern: '/**/images/**',   access:
> ['permitAll']],   [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', access: ['permitAll']],
> [pattern: '/api/login',          access: ['permitAll']] ]
>
> grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [     [pattern:
> '/assets/**',      filters: 'none'],  [pattern: '/**/js/**',
>
> filters: 'none'],     [pattern: '/**/css/**',      filters: 'none'],
> [pattern: '/**/images/**',   filters: 'none'],  [pattern:
> '/**/favicon.ico', filters: 'none'],  [           pattern: '/**',             filters:
> 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
> ],
>
> //Traditional, stateful chain   [           pattern: '/stateful/**',
> filters:
> 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'
> ] ]
>
> grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.logout.endpointUrl = '/api/logout'
> grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.generation.jwt.issuer='ash'
> grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.generation.jwt.algorithm="HS256"
> grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.jwt.secret="secret"
> grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.jwt.useSignedJwt=true
> grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.jwt.expiration=3600
>
> rails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.generation.jwt.jweAlgorithm="RSA-OAEP"
> grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.generation.jwt.encryptionMethod="A128GCM"

The response I am getting

```
{
    "username": "user1",
    "roles": [
        "ROLE_USER"
    ],
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "access_token": "l755g5o1stj8f1capi9cibtq4e5lr63p"
}
```

token here is not a JWT Token. Can any one guide me on this

Comment: `"token here is not a JWT Token"` - Do you know what it is?

Comment: JWT token has 3 part header, body, and signature, it doesn't have any .It is just any random generated token